# Jquery dosen't runs complete

Tags: jquery, callback

I have a jQuery script in my website and somewhere with 8 times callback.

The code sometimes runs normal and sometimes not (incomplete)!

Maybe cache have problem.

This address www.seta.rotsab.com

Please try two times you will see different results.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#k1,#k2,#k3,#kg,#kab,#frmcn").hide();
    var wq = "ha";
    $("#xap").click(function () {
        if (wq == "ha") {
            $("#x5,#x6,#x7,#x8,#x9,#x10,#x11,#x12,#x13,#x14,#x15,#x16,#x17,#x22").slideUp(2000, function () {
                $("#a1,#a7").slideUp(10, function () {
                    $("#app").animate({
                        top: '115px',
                        right: '800'
                    }, function () {
                        $("#app2").animate({
                            top: '115px',
                            right: '520'
                        }, function () {
                            $("#app3").animate({
                                top: '115px',
                                right: '195'
                            }, function () {
                                $("#k1,#k2,#k3").show(10, function () {
                                    $("#k1,#k2,#k3").animate({
                                        top: '240px'
                                    }, 2000);
                                    kn1.animate({
                                        top: '300',
                                        opacity: '0.4'
                                    }, "slow");


                                });
                            });
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
            wq = "ap";
        } else if (wq == "ga") {
            $("#x17,#kg").slideUp(1000, function () {
                $("#app,#app2,#app3").slideDown(1000, function () {
                    $("#k1,#k2,#k3").show(1, function () {
                        $("#k1,#k2,#k3").animate({
                            top: '200px',
                            left: '1000px'
                        }, 1000, function () {
                            $("#k1").animate({
                                top: '240px',
                                left: '1500px'
                            }, 1000, function () {
                                $("#k2").animate({
                                    top: '240px',
                                    left: '1500px'
                                }, 1000);

                            });
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
            wq = "ap";
        } else if (wq == "nw") {
            $("#kn1,#kn2,#kn3,#kn4,#kn5,#kn6").hide(1000, function () {
                $("#app").animate({
                    top: '115px',
                    right: '800'
                }, function () {
                    $("#app2").animate({
                        top: '115px',
                        right: '520'
                    }, function () {
                        $("#app3").animate({
                            top: '115px',
                            right: '195'
                        }, function () {
                            $("#k1,#k2,#k3").show(10, function () {
                                $("#k1,#k2,#k3").animate({
                                    top: '240px'
                                }, 2000);

                            });
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
            wq = "ap";
        } else if (wq == "ab") {
            $("#kab").hide(1000, function () {
                $("#app").animate({
                    top: '115px',
                    right: '800'
                }, function () {
                    $("#app2").animate({
                        top: '115px',
                        right: '520'
                    }, function () {
                        $("#app3").animate({
                            top: '115px',
                            right: '195'
                        }, function () {
                            $("#k1,#k2,#k3").show(10, function () {
                                $("#k1,#k2,#k3").animate({
                                    top: '240px'
                                }, 2000);

                            });
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
            wq = "ap";
        } else if (wq == "cn") {
            $("#frmcn").hide(1000, function () {
                $("#app").animate({
                    top: '115px',
                    right: '800'
                }, function () {
                    $("#app2").animate({
                        top: '115px',
                        right: '520'
                    }, function () {
                        $("#app3").animate({
                            top: '115px',
                            right: '195'
                        }, function () {
                            $("#k1,#k2,#k3").show(10, function () {
                                $("#k1,#k2,#k3").animate({
                                    top: '240px'
                                }, 2000);

                            });
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
            wq = "ap";
        }
    });

    $("#g2").click(function () {
        if (wq == "ha") {
            $("#x5,#x6,#x7,#x8,#x9,#x10,#x11,#x12,#x13,#x14,#x15,#x16,#a7,#app,#app2,#app3").slideUp(4000, function () {
                $("#a1").slideUp(1000, function () {
                    $("#x17").animate({
                        top: '115px',
                        left: '500'
                    }, 6000, function () {
                        $("#kg").show(1, function () {
                            $("#kg").animate({
                                left: '400px'
                            }, 6000);
                        });
                    });
                });
            });


            wq = "ga";
        } else if (wq == "ap") {
            $("#app,#app2,#app3").slideUp(1000, function () {
                $("#k1,#k2,#k3").animate({
                    right: '1400'
                }, 1500, function () {
                    $("#x17").slideDown(1000, function () {
                        $("#x17").animate({
                            top: '240px'
                        }, 1500, function () {
                            $("#kg").animate({
                                left: '400px',
                                top: '260px'
                            }, 1000);
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
            wq = "ga";
        } else if (wq == "nw") {
            $("#kn1,#kn2,#kn3,#kn4,#kn5,#kn6").hide(1000, function () {
                $("#x17").slideDown({
                    top: '115px',
                    right: '800'
                }, function () {
                    $("#kg").show(10, function () {
                        $("#kg").animate({
                            top: '240px'
                        }, 2000);
                    });
                });
            });
            wq = "ga";
        } else if (wq == "ab") {
            $("#kab").hide(1000, function () {
                $("#x17").slideDown({
                    top: '115px',
                    right: '800'
                }, function () {
                    $("#kg").show(10, function () {
                        $("#kg").animate({
                            top: '240px'
                        }, 2000);
                    });
                });
            });
            wq = "ga";
        } else if (wq == "cn") {
            $("#frmcn").hide(1000, function () {
                $("#x17").slideDown({
                    top: '115px',
                    right: '800'
                }, function () {
                    $("#kg").show(10, function () {
                        $("#kg").animate({
                            top: '240px'
                        }, 2000);
                    });
                });
            });
            wq = "ga";
        }
    });
});
```

I think the problem is multiple callback because without that code run normal. The script is too long please see a source of website .

Kind Regards

Comment: webpage unavailable ..

Comment: Please format your code properly. It will make it much easier for you and other to read.

Answer (score 0):

Please create different function for below code and call it in the script wherever you need... that might optimize the code and work properly.

```
$("#x17").slideDown({
    top: '115px',
    right: '800'
}, function () {
    $("#kg").show(10, function () {
        $("#kg").animate({
            top: '240px'
        }, 2000);
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you say please why this funcation make problem?

Comment: As you know repeating same code again-n-again is not a good practice and it may consume more memory while you run this script.